# How to delete item in Section in List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to delete an item in a Section in a List. But currently it doesn't delete the item/row that I wan't to delete.

One of my sections:

```
Section(header: Text("Upcoming")) {
    ForEach(birthdays.filter {
        $0.date!.day <= Date().day && $0.date!.month > Date().month
            ||
            $0.date!.day > Date().day && $0.date!.month > Date().month
            ||
            $0.date!.day > Date().day && $0.date!.month == Date().month
    }, id: \.self) { birthday in
        BirthdayView(birthday: birthday)
            .onAppear {
                birthdayNotification(for: birthday)
            }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteBirthdays)
}
```

My delete function:

```
func deleteBirthdays(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for offset in offsets {
        let birthday = birthdays[offset]

        // delete it from the context
        moc.delete(birthday)
    }

    // save the context
    try? moc.save()
}
```

Any clue how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because you get an offset from the **filtered** birthdays and try to delete on the **unfiltered** birthdays.

Instead of:

```
ForEach(birthdays.filter { ... }
```

create a variable for the filtered birthdays (can be `let`, `@State` etc. depending on your use-case):

```
let filteredBirthdays = birthdays.filter { ... }
```

and use both in the loop:

```
ForEach(filteredBirthdays ...
```

and in delete method:

```
let birthday = filteredBirthdays[offset]
```